# Map ioport form hardware to vDSO function

Tags: linux, vdso, ioports

I am using SAMA5d2 CPU with Linux, and want to have access to ioport from vdso function. How shoul I map ioport to userspace memory to get access to ioport in vdso function which calls from userspace?
 Actualy I want to implement getting of timer cycles in tcb_clksrc timer.
The kernel have implementation only for arch_arm_timer clocksource, and I want to make implementation for tcb_clksrc timer to use it in my SAMA

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in [evl project](https://evlproject.org/dovetail/porting/clocksource/)
In this project new clocksource USER_MIMO is implemented, and any clock driver can register in it as a hardware clock.
I ported tihs interface to my kernel and it's works file